# Ubuntu as Router / Bridge problems

Tags: networking, server, 16.04, vpn

I wanted to operate an Ubuntu16.04 as a Gateway for incoming VPN via fastd/batman and outgoing traffic to be redirected over an airvpn-tunnel (and later some more complex routing settings involving more vpn). Right now, after having installed and double checked everything, my gateway only works sporadicly, but the moment it works, everything works as it should.

Now my setup:
ens3 is the "physical" interface, as it is run as an virtual host.
mesh-vpn is the adapter from fastd
bat0 is the adapter for Batman, batman is configured in server mode
br is the bridge, where bat0 is added.

Then we have an interface called tun0 which is the airvpn tunnel. As well I have an interface which is a tunnel for ipv6 with Hurricane Electric. But this is not in use right now.

dnsmasq is configured to the bridge interface and to serve 10.68.16.1 to 10.68.31.254 with 255.255.192.0.

fastd is configured to start batman and to put the traffic there into bat0.

The bridge is configured to have 10.68.0.1 as ip and 255.255.192.0 as netmask.
The bridge then puts all traffic in a second routing table (which is not the main table, otherwise my complete host would disappear in the airvpn tunnel). Anything going to tun0 is natted in postrouting. This routing table routes dfault to 10.4.0.1 which is in tun0. But I think that part is not the problem.

Well, now most of the time, the connection doesn't work. I cant even ping 10.68.0.1, which is the bridges ip. So somewhere before the traffic seems to drop.

If I tcpdump my bridge while its not working, I only can see it's ARPening himself like "0.0.0.0 is at mac..." Thats it...

So I think - even though brctl show always tells me bat0 is in br - sometimes there is a sort of disconnect. But I have no clou how to start troubleshooting on this sporadic issue here. it's my first time ever seeing something set up properly changig the state of ok / not ok so often.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you in advance.
(Yes I could have asked in server fault as well. But it's an ubuntu which troubles me here, so I thought I'd be more specific here)